# How to make pageurl return an absolute url

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I need Twitter tweet button below every blog post.
How do I make `{% pageurl %}` return an absolute URL of that specific blog post?

Thanks

Comment: You models.py , template and view code please ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `{% pageurl my_page %}`, use `{{ my_page.full_url }}`.

Comment: full_url has no port in it, for example, I'm running wagtail at localhost:8000, but full_url only shows my localhost, no 8000

Comment: @avocado Set the port number under Settings -> Sites within the Wagtail admin.